# Do Grillers have a set amount of Smallfry?

Tags: splatoon-2

In the Griller wave of Salmon Run, a bunch of Smallfry run underneath the Griller enemy itself.

Is there a set amount of Smallfry that come with the Griller, or are more Smallfry generated by the Griller as it moves around? I want to know if it is possible to defeat all the Smallfry so that I don't have to worry about them while fighting the Griller.

Comment: Only anecdotal evidence, but from playing Salmon Run a lot I'm pretty sure there is no limit; they keep spawning. However, it does seem like they don't spawn very fast after the initial bunch that approach you along with the Griller.

Answer (score 1):

When a Griller enemy spawns, a group of Smallfry will spawn with it. During a Griller wave, Smallfry will constantly spawn, around 1 every 2-3 seconds.